# Inner box shadow that is curved

Tags: css, box-shadow

I am trying to make a sidebar that is similar to the one shown here: https://www.sketchapp.com/docs/ .I made everything working fine except making the box shadow opacity at top and bottom, I tried box shadow but couldn't make it the way its shown in the page.  [what I did so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPzla.png)

Thanks in advance! ^^

image to see

Comment: Can you post what you've done so far? It will help others help you if I cannot.

Comment: it's a gradient used with pseudo element, simply inspect the code to see it

Comment: here is the code that I used for the shadow box: 
 box-shadow: 
    inset 0px 11px 0px -1px rgba(221, 211, 211, 0.76),
    inset 0px -11px 0px -1px rgba(187, 171, 171, 0.384);

Comment: Temani, I tried that but didn't show at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.
You can use pseudo selectors and add to them a background with a linear gradient.
for example:

```
div::before {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #fcfcfc, rgba(252,252,252,0));
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

here i am doing the following:
I set the background to a linear gradient fades the color, I put display block in order to make it behave like a div, finally I set the z-index to 0 in order to place it at the top of the other elements.
here is a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hdsma1fv/5/

references:

- about pseudo elements: https://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_elements.asp
- about linear gradients: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

#### Edit:

If you need the shadow to hide with the scroll then you need to attach the pseudo selector `::before` to an element inside the scroll and remove the `position: absolute;`.
Also if you want it to show in the bottom also, you need two things: first - rotate the linear gradient angle and second - use the pseudoselector `::after` instead of the `::before` one.
check https://jsfiddle.net/hdsma1fv/34/ for an updated example with both modifications.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ^^, and thanks for the welcoming ^^

Comment: It worked fine with me, except it doesn't follow the sidenav (sticky sidenav), I tried position:sticky; it didn't work. Also if you can help me doing same effect on the downside too, I tried to change the degree didn't work made new styling with direction: down, didn't work too. Thanks in Advance, your help is really appreciated

Comment: Sure!. What do you mean by "sticky sidenav"? Do you mean the shadow to stay on top of the content so it hides when scroll down?

Comment: The gradient stays in its position, the side bar moves with the scrolling, using the sticky in position. When I apply you code the gradient stays in its position instead of scrolling with the side bar.

Comment: @Yehia check my edit, i think that  this edited example is what you are loocking for. https://jsfiddle.net/hdsma1fv/34/

Comment: That is exactly what I have, the gradient is in its place. What I want that is the items in the list to go and *disappear* into the gradient. I THANK YOU so much for your time helping me reach what I want ^^